# VBA Identify numbers within a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am sure this is a simple one but cant seem to find anything explicit out on the WWW.

I need my code to identify any numbers between 1 and 9 within a column for it to throw the error back for that range, I can only get it working with one number at present.

```
Public Sub ErrorCheck()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = ""
If VBA.Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
With Sheets("Scoring").Range("S:S")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error", True
    Else

    End If
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your code iteratively for all the values you want. Example:

```
Public Sub ErrorCheck()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim startVal As Integer, endVal As Integer

    startVal = 1
    endVal = 9

    For i = startVal To endVal
        FindString = CStr(i)
        With Sheets("Scoring").Range("S:S")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Error", True
                Exit For
            Else

            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response varocarbas! I have just fired this off and I think I am missing a library for the 'For i = startVal to endVal' part of the code. Do you know what library is required for that?  Thanks Again!

Comment: A library? This is a typical loop performing the actions from startVal (1 in this case) and endVal (9 in this case). The value being increased (i) is converted into a string and given as input to your code. That is, it is executed 10 times with 10 different inputs (if a match is found before the end, it stops trying). This is what you wanted, isn't it?... If you meant where I took this from, I created it right after seeing your question. Or if you meant what you need to execute the for...next, you don't need anything, it is one of the VBA basic commands.

Comment: That sounds spot on....but it throws a compile error when I run the code 'Can't find project or library' Thanks Again!

Comment: ?! Are you using VBA in Excel? There is nothing in the code above requiring a library. Nothing I wrote at least. Perhaps, while copying it you did something wrong (not sure what, to be honest), try it again. If your original code worked fine, this one should also work fine because I haven't included anything weird. Instead copying it, just edit your code and see how VBA recognises for (write it with small caps, and it will set it to upper caps automatically).

Comment: Closed down my session of excel and restarted...works perfectly. Thankyou very much! ;-)

Comment: No problem (although still not sure what might have provoked this error).